# JSF + Spring Using @Autowired in a ManagedBean ; Do we need setters and getters

Tags: jsf-2, setter, autowired, getter, managed-bean

I am using Spring and JSF 2.0. 
This is how my class look like
@ManagedBean(name = "userLogin", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public    class    UserLogin

in this class I am using the following property

```
@Autowired
@ManagedProperty(value   = "#{userService}")
private    UserService    userService;
```

And this is how my userService looks like

@Service  ("userService")

In a framework like struts , I can use the userService without setters and getters , as its been named as a service.
Please tell how to use this without setters and getters , as I feel like its kind of a overhead.

Basically I just want to get rid of getters and setters for the userService as its a Spring bean.

Regards
Rashen

Comment: This is how my userService class looks like
@Service("userService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {}

Comment: If you use @ManagedBean/@ManagedProperty, you need getter/setter. If you use @Component/@Autowired, you don't. Your mixing JSF/Spring, which won't work (@Autowired is not needed in your example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@ManagedProperty(value = "#{userService}")` probably does nothing here, since `UserService` is not a JSF managed bean (judging from the code in your comment). You are combining two dependency injection strategies, where you only need one (setter is required for `@ManagedProperty`).

If you remove `@ManagedProperty` and leave only `@Autowired`, I think it should work.

Comment: yes , I just used @Component with @Scope("session")